# Dynamically adding combobox in DataList / Listview

Tags: asp.net, listview, combobox, datalist

I have a web page where I have to let the user dynamically add /remove comboboxes.  I have a page I did a year ago where I used a datalist control to hold all the controls.

Is a listview control any better?  or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ListView is a bit more heavyweight than a DataList - it offers paging, sorting, and insert/edit/delete templates.  You can [read about it here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx).

If you're just changing for the sake of change, I wouldn't bother. If you actually need some of the additional functionality, then go for it.  If you're unhappy with your implementation, maybe post some of your code and it would be easier to analyze your approach.